# Error in MIPS assembly program: "Bad address in data/stack" ()

Tags: arrays, c, mips

I am new to coding and MIPS. Lately, I have been trying to translate an array and loop from C to MIPS.

```c
int i = 0;

while (user_name[i] != '\0') {
    high_score.name[i] = user_name[i];
    ++i;
}
high_score.name[i] = '\0';
```

In MIPS:

```
        li      $s2, 0

loop4:
        lb      $s3, user_name($s2)                 #
        beqz    $s3, string_endwhile                # user name[i] != "\0"

        la      $s4, high_score                     # Load the value of high_score to s4
        add     $s4, $s4, 4                         # Locate name in high_score
        add     $s4, $s4, $s2                       # s4 in the loop

        sb      $s3, high_score($s4)                # high_score.name[i] = user_name[i]

        addi    $s2, $s2, 1
        j       loop4


string_endwhile:

        la      $s4, high_score
        add     $s4, $s4, 4
        add     $s4, $s4, $s2

        sb      $zero, high_score($s4)
```

However, when I try to run, my computer notices this error:

```
Exception occurred at PC=0x0040051c
Exception occurred in game.s at line: 812: sb      $s3, high_score($s5)                 #high_score.name[i] = user_name[i]
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x2002011c
```

I tried to fix it, but I failed to do so.

Comment: The instruction stores a byte in `$s3` to `high_score($s5)`, and the error is that `high_score($s5)` is invalid. Check the value in `$s5`. Also not clear how you got to line number 812. I think the code that's running is not the code you posted.

Comment: @RaymondChen : for line 812 I just extracted a portion of my entire code, so line 812 here is equivalent to the line $s3, high_score($s5)

Comment: There is no line `$s3, high_score($s5)` in the code you posted.

Comment: The code you've posted is incorrectly using `high_score` as both an offset and part of the base address.